# How to fix "Undefined is not JSON serializable" in python flask

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

for given user input in to

```
   <button class="btn-search" type="submit" id="submit">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                  <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27C15.41 12.59 16 11.11 16 9.5 16 5.91 13.09 3 9.5 3S3 5.91 3 9.5 5.91 16 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z"></path>
                </svg>
              </button>
```

using Javascript d3 I select the input and process some cleaning and trying to send it to python where it will call an api for me. First of all this is my javascript code

```
var country_search = d3.select("#submit")

country_search.on("click", function(){
    d3.event.preventDefault();

    var user_input_country = d3.select("#user_country").node().value;
    const splitted = user_input_country.split(" ");
    d3.select("#user_country").node().value = "";

    // if no space in country name
    if (splitted.length === 1){
        user_input_country = user_input_country.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + user_input_country.slice(1).toLowerCase()
    }
    // if space --> titlecase all other than of/and,...etc.
    else{
        for (var i=0; i <splitted.length; i++) {
            // titlecase except for the word "of"
            if (splitted[i] != "of" && splitted[i] !="and"){
                splitted[i] = splitted[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + splitted[i].slice(1).toLowerCase()
            }
        }
        user_input_country = splitted.join(" ")
    }

    get_city_list(user_input_country);
})

function get_city_list(country){
    console.log(country);
    d3.json(`/cities/${user_input_country}`).then(function(response){
        console.log(`successfuly got python api ${response}`)
})
};
```

From my understanding when get_city_list function is called it will send user_input_country variable to python api and get its response. However I keep on getting "TypeError: Object of type Undefined is not JSON serializable" js and html seems to work fine when I simply open html however when I run the server it gives me this error.

I am assuming there is something wrong in python code. I've tried deleting @app.route("/cities/....) however it still gives me the same error. I've tried to jsonify returning object and still no luck. here is my python code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = 'mysql+pymysql://root:Gksmf12#@localhost:3306/aqi_db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Aqi(db.Model):
    __tablename__ ='aqi_info'
    id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Countries = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=True)
    Cities = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=True)
    aqi = db.Column(db.Integer)
    # declare how query is outputted.
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Aqi('{self.Countries}', '{self.Cities}', '{self.aqi}')"

@app.route("/")
def index():
    """Return the homepage."""
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/cities/<country>")
def cities(country):
    """ for given country
    1. get list of cities from json file.
    2. loop through each city and call api to get AQI data.
    3. store into db
    4. return {city:[], aqi:[], lat_lng:[a,b]} so heat map can be made.
    """
    print(country)
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Edit: I've tried testing bit by bit and when I render different html as soon as server load it works fine. It must be problem in html however cannot find it nor understand why.

Solution: I've finally solved it. From most unexpected place, in html. I had a code that have been commented out

```
  <!-- received data from python and putting in a script therefore js can use it. -->
  <!-- <script>
      var canadian_cities = {{canada_cities|tojson}};
      var pop = {{pop|tojson}};
  </script> -->
```

however it seemed like jinja does not consider this as a comment however reads it as a code therefore it didn't know what canada_cities was therefore when I was trying to send it to js using |tojson it kept on giving that error. This is all my understanding, please correct me if I am wrong. Finally I've simply deleted that comment and everything seems to work fine!

Comment: Take a look at where you may be serializing an `undefined` object into `JSON`. That's what the error is telling you. Perhaps if the object is `undefined` you want to make it `null` so the serialization works as expected.

Comment: Is it because I am using for loop with variable "i" in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your function cities returns nothing.
2. For Countries and Sities you need use relationship, I think so. https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many
3. Use jsonify for serialization (from flask import jsonify)

Comment: that wasn't it, I've edited the solution. Check it out.